How to send message with telethon bot api actively?
I'm testing the bot by just sending a "bot" to the demo channel:
bot = TelegramClient(
    Path("tgapi.bot.session"),
    config.api_id,
    config.api_hash
)
bot.start(bot_token=config.bot_token)


async def bot_main():
    await bot.send_message(config.demo, "bot")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(bot_main())

But when i run, it just output a banch of errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trdthg/repo/tgapi/tgapi-py/demo.py", line 20, in <module>
    asyncio.run(bot_main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/trdthg/repo/tgapi/tgapi-py/demo.py", line 16, in bot_main
    await bot.send_message(config.demo, "bot")
  File "/home/trdthg/repo/tgapi/tgapi-py/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telethon/client/messages.py", line 905, in send_message
    result = await self(request)
  File "/home/trdthg/repo/tgapi/tgapi-py/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "/home/trdthg/repo/tgapi/tgapi-py/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telethon/client/users.py", line 34, in _call
    raise RuntimeError('The asyncio event loop must not change after connection (see the FAQ for details)')
RuntimeError: The asyncio event loop must not change after connection (see the FAQ for details)
Task was destroyed but it is pending!

...

So bot can't send a message actively?

The docs explains that error here.

No, the issue is not about that; this demo matches the description in the FAQ. I spent some more time debugging and found that you need to await bot.start(). I found it in an inconspicuous corner, and if you are using the user API, you do not need to await. They are different.

The problem is asyncio.run creates a new asyncio event loop. However, you already called .start() before that, which used a different event loop.
As you point out, either move .start() inside the async def so that it uses the same loop, or use client.loop.run_until_complete instead of asyncio.run to use the default loop.
